# MongoDB: $addToSet/$push document only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a `lists` collection where each document has an array of `members`. Each element of the `members` array is a document with an `email` property, creation `date` property, and some other meta. I have a unique index on `members.email` to prevent the same email being entered into the same list twice, but I would like to retain the original `date` value. Unfortunately, neither `$addToSet` nor `$push` seem to do this.

Example using $push:

```
$lists->update(array('_id' => $list['_id'], 'members.email' => array('$ne' => $email)), array('$push' => array('members' => array(
    'email' => $email,
    'date' => new MongoDate(),
    // etc.
))));
```

And with $addToSet:

```
$lists->update(array('_id' => $list['_id']), array('$addToSet' => array('members' => array(
    'email' => $email,
    'date' => new MongoDate(),
    // etc.
))));
```

Both examples replace the entire embedded document with the new one due to (I assume) the unique `date` value. Is it possible to only `$push` the "member" document if `members.email` doesn't already exist or will I need to do this in two commands?

Alternatively, would it be better scalability-wise to put the `members` in their own collection with a `parent_list`-like property?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience the reason that you cannot "$push" or "$addToSet" is because your target "members" is probably an embedded object (or converted to one after its creation). You can only use $push, $pushAll, $addToSet on embedded arrays...

Unfortunately for us php developers a cursor query always returns the data as arrays, the best way to check to see if something like "members" is an array or object, is to run a find() in the mongo shell and look for the curly/square brackets ( "{}" or "[]" ) in the result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a collection where you store list_id, email, added_date
You would then create a unique index on 2 keys list_id and email. That would prevent insertion
of a record with the same list_id and email

There will not be embedded documents. You can still use find() by list_id

Answer (score 1):

use `$ne` in query condiction to filter documents with members of same email:

```
$lists->update(array('_id' => $list['_id'],
                     'members.email' => array('$ne' => $email)), 
               array('$addToSet' => array('members' => array(
                     'email' => $email,
                     'date' => new MongoDate(),
                      // etc.
))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Check out the $exists operator in the mongoDB [advanced queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists) section.  Code an $exists condition into a where statement to only update when the members email doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm almost positive $exists is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try using [Upsert](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-UpsertswithModifiers) to either update the embedded doc (if such one) or insert it (if none). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774827/mongodb-create-doc-if-not-exist-else-push-to-array) too.

As to you second question regarding scalability, its really case dependent... embedding the doc in the parent require harder updates and bigger data fetch, but reduce the fetch queries count.