# mongodb - create doc if not exist, else push to array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, upsert

I have a document in the following form:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4d2d8deff4e6c1d71fc29a07"),
"user_id" : "714638ba-2e08-2168-2b99-00002f3d43c0",
"events" : [
        {
                "profile" : 10,
                "data" : "....."
        }
        {
                "profile" : 10,
                "data" : "....."
        }
        {
                "profile" : 20,
                "data" : "....."
        }
        ...
   ]
 }
```

I'd like to have some sort of `upsert` statement. It needs to add an `event` to the `events` array for `user_id` in case there is already such doc exist, else it needs to create the doc with the `event` item.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do upserts in Mongo, see "Upserts with Modifiers" from the [Mongo doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating):

> You may use upsert with a modifier
>   operation. In such a case, the
>   modifiers will be applied to the
>   update criteria member and the
>   resulting object will be inserted.

The query you need will look like:

```
db.events.update( { "user_id" : "714638ba-2e08-2168-2b99-00002f3d43c0" }, 
{ $push : { "events" : { "profile" : 10, "data" : "X"}}}, {"upsert" : true});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm using a different version, but with only true as the last update parameter it doesn't work. I had to put {upsert: true} as the argument.

Comment: @Javier Ferrero Example shows only $push, what about if there are fields like user_type after user_id also has to be updated..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar, then combine: `{ $set: {...}, $push: {...} }`

Comment: Note - use $addToSet instead of $push.  You probably don't want duplicate elements.

Comment: For people using pymongo its `upsert=True` named param style and not json style.