# How do I atomically add an entry into a MongoDB array

Tags: python, mongodb, atomic

I have multiple publish/subscribe servers that attempt to update a MongoDB database as events occur. Currently I am running into an issue where I need to atomically add entries to a given MongoDB document array, but am running into a race condition when it comes to who adds the entry into the document. I'm attempted to use `$addToSet` to accomplish the add. However, since the array entry can get updated once the entry is within the array it makes it difficult for addToSet to work properly since it does a direct comparison to see if the entry is within the array or not. The end result as shown below is I get multiple servers adding in a new entry to the array.

Below is an example of a finished document that I would like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("522f99a622927d6d65b81dbd"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "type" : "out",
            "uuid" : "4f501517-1d10-48c2-91b7-0ca1bda80bd5",
            "member_id" : "3847",
            "join" : ISODate("2013-09-10T17:13:58.881Z")
        }
    ],
    "created" : ISODate("2013-09-10T17:13:58.437Z"),
    "name" : "entry"
}
```

Below is an example of what's happening due to the race condition:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("522f99a622927d6d65b81dbd"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "type" : "out",
            "uuid" : "4f501517-1d10-48c2-91b7-0ca1bda80bd5",
            "member_id" : "3847",
            "join" : ISODate("2013-09-10T17:13:58.881Z")
        },
        {
            "type" : "out",
            "uuid" : "4f501517-1d10-48c2-91b7-0ca1bda80bd5",
            "member_id" : "3847",
            "join" : ISODate("2013-09-10T17:13:58.881Z")
        }
    ],
    "created" : ISODate("2013-09-10T17:13:58.437Z"),
    "name" : "entry"
}
```

Has anyone successfully been able to atomically add/modify array entries within a document without having to move the array data out of the collection entirely? I know that by moving it out of the collection it allows me to build a unique constraint against the entry, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Comment: Operations within mongodb are always atomic at document level. Did you verify your application code for any possible bugs? For the array element to be added twice within a document, you **have to call it twice**.

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple servers are in play here, which is contributing to this condition. Although the document is atomic due to the nature of MongoDB, using $addToSet just isn't enough to ensure an entry goes in only if it does not exist. Mostly because the array object changes and $addToSet does not really account for that when it does its direct compare. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I see the point you are trying to make, but I would like to bring to your notice that mongodb does obtain [lock while performing writes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/). Also, [writes at document level](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/) always atomic. So while your point about $addToSet may be valid, it doesn't mean that mongoDb will execute $addToSet twice. And to have the data you have shown, it needs to call $addToSet twice. If there is nothing wrong in your application code (which I suggest you should re-verify to be sure), its a bug with mongoDB!

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback! However, since we have multiple servers attempting to run $addToSet almost at the same time due to the pub/sub event it does not allow MongoDB to do a proper check before adding the entry to the array. Again, most likely due to the fact that the entry's keys/values get updated after it's been initially placed into the array.

Comment: I found the following post that I have found helpful. Instead of using $addToSet I can just use $push with the proper criteria.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774827/mongodb-create-doc-if-not-exist-else-push-to-array

Comment: Scratch the idea of using $push. I may just need to move the array outside of it's current collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to move the array into it's own collection to enforce a unique constraint against uuid, which then will cause inserts with the same uuid to fail. There is a feature request to provide that, which you can see at: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1068.

Let me know if I can help you with anything else.

Best,
Charlie