# Mongodb: Create or update different part of document based on existence

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Team,

I have to create the below document when the document not exists (find_on_user).

```
{
      "st"          :  "s",       //current status s=sent, d=delivered, u=undelivered, r=resent
      "u"           :  "user",
      "e"           :  [         
                       //HISTORY OF EVENTS "s" - status at the time of each event
                {"c": "2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac", "s":"s", "@":ISODate("2017-01-29T08:43:00Z")}
      ]
}
```

If exists, for successive above events i have to update only the event array. Note latest status("st") in the main document also getting updated as per the new event added into the array.

```
{
      "st"          :  "r",       //current status s=sent, d=delivered, u=undelivered, r=resent
      "u"           :  "user",
      "e"           :  [         
                       //HISTORY OF EVENTS "s" - status at the time of each event
                {"c": "2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac", "s":"s", "@":ISODate("2017-01-29T08:53:00Z")},
                {"c": "2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac", "s":"u", "@":ISODate("2017-01-29T09:43:00Z")},
                {"c": "2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac", "s":"r", "@":ISODate("2017-01-29T10:43:00Z")}
      ]
}
```

I think what i want is upsert along with $push

```
db.collection.update(query, update, {upsert: true})

DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject("e", new BasicDBObject("c","2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac").append("s","r").append("@",ISODate("2017-01-29T10:43:00Z"));
DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$push", listItem);
myCol.update(findQuery, updateQuery);
```

How to do this together in mongodb spring data? Please help.

Question is something very similar to [mongodb - create doc if not exist, else push to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774827/mongodb-create-doc-if-not-exist-else-push-to-array)

But this is not telling about how to update outer document("st") along with $push? also this answer is dealing with String Json, is that possible via a java object?

From Veeram Answer:

---

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("u").is("user"));

DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject("c","2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac").append("s","r").append("@",new Date());

Update update = Update.update("st","r").push("e", listItem);

mongoOperations.upsert(query, update, collection_name);
```

since i have only two params like "u", "st" Veeram has used one at query and one at update. What will happen when i have more than two, but those to be updated only at the time of insert, later only status("st") get updated.

Example below "type" and "account_id" will be added at the time of insert, later update will be done only at "st". How to solve this?

```
{
      "st"          :  "s",       //current status s=sent, d=delivered, u=undelivered, r=resent
      "u"           :  "user",
      "type"        :  "welcome-sms",
      "account_id"  :  "12as-df23-fg-1",
      "e"           :  [         
                       //HISTORY OF EVENTS "s" - status at the time of each event
                {"c": "2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac", "s":"s", "@":ISODate("2017-01-29T08:43:00Z")}
      ]
```

Do i need to use like below? But type and account_id are static. needs to be updated only at first(insert) time. Is that fine?

```
Update updateObj = Update.update("st","r")
updateObj.set("type", "welcome-sms");
updateObj.set("account_id", "12as-df23-fg-1").push("e", listItem);
```

Comment: Somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436542/mongodb-java-push-into-array but not fully answering my question.

Comment: Another relevant item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974216/is-there-an-upsert-option-in-mongodb-insert-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("u").is("user"));

DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject("c","2b3de827-ac38-4023-5950-819947858eac").append("s","r").append("@",new Date());

Update updateObj = Update.update("st","r")

updateObj.setOnInsert("type", "welcome-sms");
updateObj.setOnInsert("account_id", "12as-df23-fg-1").push("e", listItem);

mongoOperations.upsert(query, updateObj, collection_name);
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks!! Let me check and confirm.

Comment: I have updated my query to address some thing specific to your answer. Could you please check and revert?

Comment: You are welcome. Updated answer to include [setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) for `type` and `account_id`. Please verify.